# Size charts side by side

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have two charts side by side in my form (using `Windows.Form.Charting`). They are structured, at least as far as I can tell, identically (same size, same properties), the only difference being their positions. However, when I add titles to the two charts, the leftmost chart gets a title starting a little bit down below the top of the control, whereas on the rightmost chart, the title appears right at the top of the control. Does anyone know why this could be the case?

Comment: Well there __must__ be something different in the titles. They have __many__ properties. Or maybe a linefeed or newline character has sneaked in..

Comment: not that I can find, it seems like they've somehow been preset to be at different positions, I've been pretty thorough looking for anything like that. When I take the titles away the graph's Y-axis' have different heights though

Comment: hmm, well I couldn't find anything, but putting two new lines commands in the title of the rightmost chart seemed to solve it, by making both of the titles start at the same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, so it turns out the left chart had a title default added to it, which had an alignment of middle center. This caused any other titles added to it to also have that same alignment. Additionally, when there are no titles in the collection, and one is added (the case in the leftmost graph), its default value for alignment is top, hence the difference. Not sure why one chart had a default title or why it wasn't appearing, but this explains how the properties could look the same at a glance. The only way to catch it would be to go inside the title properties window, which their wasn't really a reason to because no titles were initially showing up on either graph.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.title.docking(v=vs.110).aspx